# Why is maven installing to the wrong place?

Tags: java, maven-2

I try to run a mvn install, it compiles fine, but for some reason maven is trying to install to this location:

```
[INFO] Installing /home/username/workspace/projectname/pom.xml to 
/home/username/workspace/projectname/?/.m2/repository/artifactname/artifact.pom
```

Note, the location has a ? in it.  This location really needs to be the home directory/.m2.  Any idea what's causing it to install to the wrong location?

Edit: 
Executing mvn --help:effective-settings gives:

```
  <localRepository xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0">
      /home/username/workspace/projectname/?/.m2/repository
  </localRepository>
```

Interestingly enough, if I run mvn --help:effective-settings from a different directory, say: /tmp, it gives:

```
  <localRepository xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0">
      /tmp/?/.m2/repository
  </localRepository>
```

Comment: Maven has its own ideas about where things belong. This could be its way of telling you to get used to it from the get-go.

Comment: Why does it install in workspace/projectname at all? Normally its $HOME/.m2

Comment: @extraneon Yes, that's where I want it to go-- $HOME/.m2.  I have no idea why it's getting installed to the wrong location.

Comment: There is definitely something weird (looks like a global problem). Did things work before? Are you using Maven for the first time with this machine/user? Is this a new environment?

Comment: It is a fresh install of maven for the user.  Right now, it works if the user specifies the localRepository in their global settings.xml, but it ignores whatever gets put in the .m2/settings.xml.  The crazy part is all the environment variables look fine when she does 'printenv'.

Comment: @Cuga Yes, it ignores `~/.m2/settings.xml` because the Java system property `user.home` is currently broken (so the `${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml` won't be found). That's the root cause of all problems and it need to be fixed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please run the following goal on your project:

```
mvn help:effective-settings
```

And check the value of `localRepository` (and update the question with the value).

**Follow-up:** Ok, so far, things are coherent. Next...

The default value of `localRepository` is supposed to be `${user.home}/.m2/repository`. Double check that you aren't overriding it in:

- The `settings.xml` from the Maven install: `$M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml`
- The `settings.xml` from the user's install: `${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml`

If you aren't, check the actual value of `${user.home}` (run the following command on your project):

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.1.1:evaluate -Dexpression=user.home
```

If you don't get the expected value, check the actual value of `%USERPROFILE%` if you're on Windows.

**Follow-up 2:** I'm not sure how `${user.home}` gets valued exactly under Linux but this previous question [Java: System.getProperty(“user.home”) returns “?”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503284/java-system-getpropertyuser-home-returns) describes the same weird behavior - and a workaround: **using a  [64-bit JDK on a 64-bit system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503284/java-system-getpropertyuser-home-returns/1508616#1508616)**.

What JDK are you using exactly? On what platform? Could you be in the same situation (in which case, I really think it's a JDK bug, a 32-bit JDK should return the right value on a 64-bit system too).

**Follow-up 3:** This is actually [Bug ID: 6972329](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6972329) (which is not confirmed as a JDK bug, it could be a system bug).

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question to have the output.  And tried it from a different location and the value changes.

Comment: Running that command (ending in -Dexpression=user.home) returns ? as the output.  On linux doing 'echo ~' and 'echo $HOME' both go to the user's correct home: /home/username.  This is really bugging me

Comment: Since it changes when you change directories I suspect one of your environment variables that affects user.home is set to the current directory "."

Comment: @Chris:  Do you have any advice how we can check if this is the case?

Comment: You're exactly right. System.getProperty("user.home"); returns: ? on a 64 bit Fedora 11 running a 32 bit JDK v 1.6.0_21.  Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Check out the value of localRepository in [settings.xml](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html).

Comment: I checked-- there's no value set, it should be the default.  In fact, I'm rather certain it's not even seeing settings.xml in ~.m2, since it doesn't know to install stuff there.

Comment: @Cuga at this point I would be tempted to do a `grep -r -H "workspace/projectname"` on the entire /home/username and see where this is mentioned. Though Pascal's answer is certainly better.

Answer (score 0):

See your environment variables ! 
Check that you do not have set the "MAVEN_OPTS" variable as that will override all other settings.

I had cut&paste-ed that from another machine not noticing it had : "-Dmaven.repo.local=XXXX" in it. (blush)