# Configuring known_hosts in jgit

Tags: java, git, ssh, jsch, jgit

Using jgit with gitolite for source control, I have an application that generates certain code on command and which we want to be committed to source control.  The goal is to pull with a fast forward, commit the new code, and then push it.

I have the following method:

```
private void commitToGitRepository(String updateComment, Config config)
      throws IOException, NoFilepatternException, GitAPIException
{
   if(git == null)
   {
      git = Git.open(new File(config.getDpuCheckoutDir()));
   }
   PullCommand pull = git.pull();
   pull.call();
}
```

This method fails on the `pull.call()` method call, with the following exception:

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: UnknownHostKey: www.somehost.com. RSA key fingerprint is 9d:92:a9:c5:5d:cb:5f:dc:57:ff:38:7e:34:31:fe:75
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.checkHost(Session.java:748)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:319)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.JschConfigSessionFactory.getSession(JschConfigSessionFactory.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.SshTransport.getSession(SshTransport.java:121)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh$SshFetchConnection.<init>(TransportGitSsh.java:248)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.TransportGitSsh.openFetch(TransportGitSsh.java:147)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.executeImp(FetchProcess.java:136)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.FetchProcess.execute(FetchProcess.java:122)
at org.eclipse.jgit.transport.Transport.fetch(Transport.java:1104)
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.FetchCommand.call(FetchCommand.java:128)
at org.eclipse.jgit.api.PullCommand.call(PullCommand.java:245)
at net.intellidata.dpu.controller.schema.EntityMappingController.commitToGitRepository(EntityMappingController.java:149)
... (truncated where it meets my code)
```

The way I read this, it seems that it's not finding my known_hosts file in `user_home/.git`.  However, I've been searching for an hour and I'm not finding a way to configure JGit to tell JSch where to look for the known_hosts file.

Suggestions?  I know the entry for the origin is present in my known_hosts file

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14024709/6309) mentions:

```
jsch.setKnownHosts("C:\\Users\\aUsername\\known_hosts");
```

But you are using jgit, and *not* [jsch (the Java secure shell)](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) directly, so let's see:

```
C:\Users\VonC\prog\git>git clone https://github.com/eclipse/jgit
Cloning into 'jgit'...
remote: Counting objects: 37854, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (7743/7743), done.
remote: Total 37854 (delta 22009), reused 34367 (delta 18831)
Receiving objects: 100% (37854/37854), 6.73 MiB | 1.37 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (22009/22009), done.

C:\Users\VonC\prog\git>cd jgit

C:\Users\VonC\prog\git\jgit>grep -nrHI "setKnownHosts" *
org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/transport/JschConfigSessionFactory.java:262:                              sch.setKnownHosts(in);
```

Found it!

This comes from [`JschConfigSessionFactory.java#knownHosts()`](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/transport/JschConfigSessionFactory.java#L258), and looks like:

```
new File(new File(home, ".ssh"), "known_hosts");
# with:
home = fs.userHome();
```

`userHome` is based on [System.getProperty("user.home")](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/util/FS.java#L242-L251).

So make sure your java session has a [`user.home` defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503284/java-system-getpropertyuser-home-returns), and that you have a `%USERPROFILE%/.ssh/known_hosts` file in there.

(`user.home` should be set by java to `%USERPROFILE%` for Windows, that is, if you are on Windows: in some case, [this won't always work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134338/java-user-home-is-being-set-to-userprofile-and-not-being-resolved)).

---

Now if you *do* have a `%USERPROFILE%/.ssh/known_hosts`, then, as [mentioned here](http://fileit.in/p/549)

> Just SSH to the client (using command-line `ssh` tool), this will add entry to your `~/.ssh/known_hosts file`.

---

In this case, the [StormeHawke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1036285/stormehawke) mentions in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843399/configuring-known-hosts-in-jgit/15849893#comment22614468_15849893):

> since I'm running this in **Tomcat as a windows service**, Jsch (and by extension JGit) was looking not in my user folder but in the **`SYSTEM` account's home folder** for the `.ssh` folder.
>   In this case I went ahead and just copied the `.ssh` folder into the `SYSTEM` home folder since Tomcat only runs on my machine for development and testing purposes (Probably not the best security policy but the risk is minimal in this case).

From [this question](https://serverfault.com/q/9325/783), [this one](https://serverfault.com/q/112927/783), that directory for the [LocalSystem Account](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684190%28VS.85%29.aspx) should be:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Default User
# or Wind7 / 2008
C:\Windows\System32\Config\systemprofile
```

The OP mentions:

According to this call:

```
 System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.home"));
```

**the default `SYSTEM` home directory for Windows7 (and presumably any other NT-based Windows system) is simply `C:\`**.
(so not ideal, but for a quick fix, it works).

Comment: You, sir, are a genius.  I'd been beating my head against the wall trying to figure out why it wasn't recognizing the known_hosts entry when I suddenly realized that, since I'm running this in Tomcat as a windows service, Jsch (and by extension JGit) was looking not in _my_ user folder but in the _SYSTEM_ account's home folder for the .ssh folder.  In this case I went ahead and just copied the .ssh folder into the SYSTEM home folder since Tomcat only runs on my machine for development and testing purposes (Probably not the best security policy but the risk is minimal in this case).  Thanks!

Comment: @StormeHawke Excellent! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility. What was the directory for your SYSTEM account? I have put some suggestions, but I am unsure of the exact location.

Comment: According to this call:
`System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.home"));`
the default SYSTEM home directory for Windows7 (and presumably any other NT-based Windows system) is simply `C:\\`

Comment: @StormeHawke ok, so you simply copied the `.ssh` directory in `C:\`, and it worked?

Comment: Correct.  I wouldn't recommend this solution for production environments since C:\ is not exactly a "secure" location.  If this were a production server I would have followed your advice and set a system variable to set user.home