# Why does my `user.home` Java system property equal `?`?

Tags: java

My `user.home` system property is `?`, instead of the home directory (`$HOME` has good value).
I've discovered this because Maven tries to put its local repo inside `./?/.m2`.

The problem is demonstrated by this small test case (taken from [Change user.home system property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501235/change-user-home-system-property))

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.home"));
  }
}
```

and

```
javac Test.java
$ javac Test.java 
$ java Test
?
```

My only environment variable starting with `JAVA` is `$JAVA_HOME` (pointing to a openjdk-15.0.1-ga), and there is no environment variable starting with `_JAVA`

If it matters, the system is CentOS 7.8.

Comment: check variable $HOME, and if it's empty try to see `HOME=/myhome java Test`

Comment: `echo $HOME` returns `/home/zvikah`

Comment: 1. As you said, this question is duplicate. Should I delete it?
2. I actually found a similar, but different answer. Added it to the other question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67615939/1543290